# burning the code to atmega328p

Tags: microcontroller, programming, atmel, atmega328p, bootloader

I am a bit confused regarding the code uploading process to the atmega328p. I have read a [site](https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/programming-atmega328p-microcontroller-with-arduino-ide/) where usb-ttl was used to upload the code. There is not bootloader uploaded on the atmega328p and the code is uploaded directly using the converter. Is it possible to upload the code in this way? i.e. without adding the arduino bootloader or not?? Kindly clarify this a bit.

Comment: Do you have an arduino to hand? If so, see [Arduino as ISP](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

But only if the USB UART chip has drivers that allows arbitrary usage of the pins as GPIO, and the programming software running on PC can set and use the chip in this mode, so the AVR ISP programming protocol can be used to flash anything you want to the chip.

Comment: But why do we see such a behavior by the chip. Arduino also uses a USB-TTL but it needs a bootloader.

Comment: That's why I said the special requirements when this is possible. In other words, not all USB UART chips have this feature, your PC might have no drivers for this feature, and programs don't support that special feature on these chips, so most chips are only standard UARTs and you can't use them as ISP programmers.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the ATmega328P as an Arduino, you need to upload the Arduino bootloader to it. You can do that with another Arduino board. If you do not want to use the ATmega328P as an Arduino, you can simply use it like any other AVR microcontroller. You do not need to burn the Arduino bootloader to it. You can program it with an AVR programmer. Such as-USBASP.

Comment: I think this does not answer the question that was asked.